# how can I exit an ijnterior loop of a nested loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

I have this program, and I am wondering how I can end an interior loop of a nested loop. Specifically how can I return the interior loop (selection "t") and return it to the outside loop if the user selects not to continue tossing the coin? I've truncated part of my code, but I don't understand how I can return back to the main loop.

```
*{       
        Scanner anotherScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean usersSelection = false;
        String c;
        while (!usersSelection)
        {
            System.out.println(""
                    + "Selection: ");
            if (anotherScanner.hasNext("q|Q"))
            {
                c = anotherScanner.next();
                usersSelection = true;
                System.out.println("you have selected to quit. If you wish to resume, reboot the program.");
                break;
            }
            if (anotherScanner.hasNext("t|T"))
            {
                c = anotherScanner.next();
                usersSelection = true;

                Scanner obtain = new Scanner(System.in);

                        System.out.println("Please enter the number of coin flips");
                        int numero = obtain.nextInt();
                        if (numero > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {

                                int alpha = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                                int beta = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                                System.out.println(alpha + " " + beta);
                            }
                        }


                        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Please enter yes or no.");
                        String response = obtain.next();
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {System.out.print("oh yeah");}

                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {break;} 

                        else 
                        {
                            String boom = obtain.next();
                            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid option. '"+boom+"' is not a valid option.");
                        }}
                }*
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a label before the loop:

```
outer:
while (!usersSelection) {
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Then replace the `break;` with `break outer;`.